# Will same source code from Visual Studio Xamarin run the same on iOS, Raspberry PI, and LattePanda?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xamarin, raspberry-pi, windows-10-iot-core

I need to write backend processing software that will also communicate over WiFi with other processes.  We want it to eventually operate in a small form factor.

Visual Studio now has Xamarin.  If I write this software with Xamarin on VS for a Windows console app, will it also work uploaded to Windows IoT CORE on Raspberry PI3B and Windows 10 on LattePanda and onto an iPad Pro?

Raspberry PI / LattePanda, and iPad (for the GUI) are the system platforms we're considering, since we could then stick to .NET end-to-end (or fall back on MSVC to solve possible performance issues).

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio, the template can build for cross-platform(Android, iOS and Windows/UWP).But when you deploy the app,you need to change the target processor, such as x86 or ARM.

In addition, please take a look at [Xamarin.IoT](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/iot/).Xamarin.IoT enables developers to write and share C# code across devices, now including internet of things devices such as Raspberry Pi and Intel Edison. It works with any IoT device running Linux (most popular distributions) and integrates seamlessly with the Azure IoT Suite to connect, analyze, and secure your IoT solutions.